# Aggregate Messages in Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

My current application is in spring Integration with Spring batch. i want to port it on spring cloud streams and spring cloud task. Is there is any document defining this .... configuring Spring integration xml configuration in Spring cloud stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue to use xml configuration, if you so wish, in a Spring Boot application, simply use `@ImportResource("my-context.xml")`.

Comment: Thanks .. i will try this